# UPDATE-SELECT Consistency Issue In Read Committed

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Read Committed isolation level, I would expect the following to deadlock since UPDATE statement will mark the row dirty and SELECT should not be able to read the row before transaction is committed or rolled back. But it seems to work without a deadlock. How does this happen?

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE TableA
SET Col2 = Col2 + 3
WHERE ID = 50

SELECT Col2 from TableA WHERE ID = 50

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: You are inside active tranasction so you see any changes from `BEGIN TRAN`. Try do the same from another session and compare.

Comment: If a transaction could not see the rows it is changing it would totally defeat the point wouldn't it? Any query outside the scope of this transaction cannot see the data that is locked (assuming you don't have isolation levels or query hints to override this).